# How to send a multi line sms with adb

Tags: android, adb

After researching a while on how to send SMS's through ADB, I found a post that led me to this command:

`adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+mynumberhere" s16 "null" s16 'Text Goes Here' s16 "null" s16 "null"`

This command works just fine to send single line text, but I want to be able to format the SMS to be multiple lines, for example:

```
This is line 1 of the SMS
This is line 2 of the SMS
And this is line 3
```

I have tried to change the `'Text Goes Here'` part to the following with no success:

```
"Test \n Test"
"Test /n Test"
"Test %n Test"
'Test \n Test'
'Test /n Test'
'Test %n Test'
"'Test\nTest'"
"'Test \n Test'"
"'Test/nTest'"
"'Test /n Test'"
"'Test'\n'Test'"
```

Absolutely none of them work and I can't find any method to solve this problem, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

adb shell "NL=$'\n' ; am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY ${NL} GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true"

Comment: Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=sms:xxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 pkg=BODY (has extras) }

Comment: please make sure that
you are in developer mode
unplug your cable and plug in again.
kill-server
start-server
i tried worked perfect for me.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!